# How do I search for a key press asynchronously in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm writing an application which requires key presses to be monitored in the background. This is the current code I'm using, with which I've tried many different methods of detecting key presses and debugged using breakpoints to no success. I should mention (if it's not obvious) that I'm new to asynchronous programming and I still only understand it on a very low level.

```
     private async void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        await KeyboardPressSearch();
    }
    private static async Task<bool> KeyboardPressSearch()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
 
        while (true)
        {

            if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
            {
                var p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\REAPER (x64)\reaper.exe";
                p.Start();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

What would you recommend I do or change? Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered handling the [`KeyPress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress) event of the `Form`, after setting its [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview) property to `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Theodor Zoulias mentioned in the comments, you can achieve this behavior by setting `Form.KeyPreview` to `true` and registering the `KeyPress` event.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
    {
        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\REAPER (x64)\reaper.exe";
        p.Start();

        //e.Handled = true if you don't want the other controls to see this keypress
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This code will now by definition be asynchronous, since it doesn't wait until the keypress, but reacts to it. If you **really** need to `await` a `Task` object somewhere, one that will complete once this event's condition is satisfied, use `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
public Task KeyboardPressSearch()
{
    // Invoking is used so that localFunc() is always executed on the UI thread.
    // locks or atomic operations can be used instead
    return 
        InvokeRequired 
        ? Invoke(localFunc) 
        : localFunc();

    Task localFunc()
    {
        taskCompletionSource ??= new();
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}

private TaskCompletionSource? taskCompletionSource;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
    {
        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\REAPER (x64)\reaper.exe";
        p.Start();

        //e.Handled = true if you don't want the other controls to see this keypress
        e.Handled = true;

        if(taskCompletionSource is not null)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult();
            taskCompletionSource = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Unfortunately I didn't have any success with either of the examples you gave. I set Form.KeyPreview to true but it still didn't work for the first one. I'm using .NET 5.0, and it says on Microsoft docs Keypress only works up to 4.8 so that might be why. On the second one, I got the error "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Delegate' " where it says " ? Invoke(localFunc) ".

Comment: For the first problem, the problem is not in .Net version, as I tested out the functionality on both .Net 5 and 6, did you perhaps forget to register the Form1_KeyDown as KeyDown event in the designer? For the second problem, when using .Net 5 replace `Invoke(localFunc)`  with `(Task)Invoke(new Func<Task>(localFunc))`

Comment: I apparently did not register it in the designer. Just did that now and it works. Thank you for your help!